# Logic-Calculating Cd Failures

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, logic

I am working on homework and have the problem

At a company every 4th CD is tested, the testing consists of 4 testing programs and the probability that they fail are as follow

Program 1 : .01
Program 2 : .03
Program 3 : .02
Program 4 : .01

What is the probability that a CD was tested and failed any test?

After working out the problem I got

(.01+.03+.02+.01)-(.01*.02*.03*.01) = .069

Is this correct?

Comment: 'failed any test'= failed at least one test or failed all tests?

Comment: Hint: If we assume independence (**very** unreasonable) the probability a CD passes all (given that it is tested) is $(0.99)(0.98)(0.97)(0.99)$.